# Mysql remove a special charecter which occurs after a specific special character

Tags: mysql

The data in a cell is like "**0^0^@1@^0^0^1^0**" , I want it to be **0^0^@1@0^0^1^0** .  Basically what I am looking for is , I want to remove the special character "^" that occurs after "@". Just note that the remaining "^" should remain as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, '@^', '@')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
mysql> SELECT REPLACE('0^0^@1@^0^0^1^0', '@^', '@');
       ->  0^0^@1@0^0^1^0
```